# Запятая перед будучи

Tags: пунктуация

Павел будучи раненным остался прикрывать свою группу. Нужно ли выделить запятыми "будучи раненным"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Нужно ли** выделить запятыми "будучи раненным"?

**Конечно.** "Будучи раненным" -- деепричастный оборот.